# asp.net division followed by formatting

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code:

```
<tr>
   <td class="add_border_bold" nowrap="nowrap">Schedule Saved (days)</td>
   <td width="100%" class="add_border">
      <%# Eval("schedule_saved_days", "{0:0,0}")%>
         &nbsp;
   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td class="add_border_bold" nowrap="nowrap">Scheduled Saved in Months</td>
   <td width="100%" class="add_border">
      <%# Eval("schedule_saved_days", "{0:0,0}")%>
      &nbsp;
   </td>
</tr>
```

What the requirement is, is to display the second 'schedule saved' in months, rather than days (for some reason they can't figure it out based on days). previously in coldfusion i had just been dividing the number by 30. i had tried a couple different things like `<%# Eval("schedule_saved_days"/30, "{0:0,0.00}")%>` and `<%# Eval("schedule_saved_days/30)%>` just to get something to work. i'm sure this is a quick fix and my google-fu is failing me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your code sample to be readable. Why make _everyone_ scroll to see what you posted?

Comment: sorry, thought the code tags handled white space better than that.

Comment: i get an error that operator '/' cannot be applied to type string or int. (i've tried schedule_saved_days as a float and an int)

i have the value 120 displaying fine in the top row, i'd like the value 4 to show up based on that. but if the value was 135, it should display as 4.5 (up to two decimal places) i know that means `{0:0,0}` has to be `{0:0,0.00}`, but i don't know how to make the division happen first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<%#(Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("schedule_saved_days")) / 30).ToString("0,0")%>
```

Comment: still get `Error 482 Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'`

Comment: actually, you got it, was just missing another parenthesis `<%#(Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("schedule_saved_days")) / 30).ToString("0.00")%>`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you are after:

```
<%# (Eval("schedule_saved_days") / 30).ToString("0,0")%>
```

Comment: "Error 56 Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cast it as an integer first and then divide by 30

```
<%# ((int)Eval("schedule_saved_days", "{0:0,0}")/30).tostring() %>
```

Comment: `Error 483 Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'`